# How can i send UDS messages through CAPL without using CDD fille

Tags: capl

Currently I am using a CDD file for accessing signal in CAPL program. Now I am trying to send the UDS signal without CDD file. Is there any options for the same?

Answer (score 1):

It is called *basic diagnostics*.

In the diagnostics configuration window, where you normally would assign a CDD to an ECU, you can chose something like „Add Basic Diagnostics (UDS)“.

After doing this and confirming the dialog, there is a basic diagnostics editor, where you can configure UDS like services and their parameters.

Sending the requests and handling the response is then the same as with a CDD.

Comment: Spiller  I have two ECUs connected in RBS,How can i select particular ECU in the UDS configuration. Now I am getting the positive response but it is not reflecting in the connected ECUs.

Comment: What do you mean by *selecting particular ECU*? You say that you are getting a positive response, but this is not coming from your simulated ECUs? Where else should it be coming from?

Comment: We Have two real ECU connected with RBS configuration. But after sending extended session getting positive response(May be from simulated node) but not reflected in the real ECU

Comment: I do not really understand the problem. When it works with a CDD it will also work with basic diagnostics. In case you have other problem it might be better to open a new question.

Comment: You have incorrect address selected then? In physical addressing (which I assume you are using),, each node should have certain address which it responds to according to UDS.

Answer (score -1):

**you need to create your own library to handle Diagnostic.**
**CAPL Diag Function only support Diagnostic Object from CDD.**

but there is an easy way for CAPL to send Diagnostic with the help of existing CDD/standard UDS CDD (example CDD from CANoe installation):
for example: I want to send Diag Req **$22 F1 F0**.

case 1: but this DID F1F0 is not defined in CDD. 
in CDD have already defined $22 F1 16 (ECU_Identification_Hardware_Part_Number).
you should be able to see in Symbol Windows: the Service "ECU_Identification_Hardware_Part_Number_Read" under ECU name "yourECU"
then you could do as follow

```
on key 'x'
{
  diagrequest yourECU.ECU_Identification_Hardware_Part_Number_Read req;
  write("send new DID $22 F1 F0");
  DiagSetPrimitiveByte(req,1,0xF1);
  DiagSetPrimitiveByte(req,2,0xF0);
  DiagSendRequest(req);
}
```

case 2: use Standard UDS CDD from CANoe.

- goto Menu Diagnostics > Diagnostics/ISO TP Configuration
- CAN Networks > CAN1 or your Channel
- add Diagnostic Description > add Standard Diagnostic Description (CDD) > GenericUDS
- rename ECU qualifier ex: yourECU
- OK
- open CAPL Editor

now you should be able to see in Symbol Windows the Diagnostic Object.
then you could drag and drop the Service you want to code ex:

```
on key 'x'
{
  diagrequest yourECU.ReadDataByIdentifier_Process req;
  DiagSetPrimitiveByte(req,1,0xF1);
  DiagSetPrimitiveByte(req,2,0x90);
  DiagSendRequest(req);
}
```

However, you can change the service by first Primitive Byte ex:

```
DiagSetPrimitiveByte(req,0,0x10); // Session Control
```

Note: the ECU Diag Request/Response ID have to be take care in config Menu Diagnostics > Diagnostics/ISO TP Configuration > CAN Networks > your CAN channel > yourECU > Transport Layer